# Lenovo Slim 9-14ITL05 (Type 82D2) - poor web camera quality

Tags: 22.04, lenovo, webcam

I just installed Ubuntu 22.04 on my newly bought laptop and faced a lot of issues, including not working keyboard, screen tearing, webcam quality.
I managed to fix all of them, except the web camera quality.
I can't find anyone with this laptop, who faced the same problem.

I tried all software ways to test/configure camera - cheese, guvcview, webcamoid, webcamtests.com, but no changes, it's still far from any reasonable quality.

I should mention that it works perfectly fine in Windows 11 (but there, the microphone is too quiet and I'm still can't use conference software.

v4l2-ctl --list-devices

```
Integrated Camera: Integrated C (usb-0000:00:14.0-1):
  /dev/video0
  /dev/video1
  /dev/video2
  /dev/video3
  /dev/media0
  /dev/media1
```

v4l2-cl -d /dev/video0 --all

```
Driver Info:
  Driver name      : uvcvideo
  Card type        : Integrated Camera: Integrated C
  Bus info         : usb-0000:00:14.0-1
  Driver version   : 5.15.53
  Capabilities     : 0x84a00001
    Video Capture
    Metadata Capture
    Streaming
    Extended Pix Format
    Device Capabilities
  Device Caps      : 0x04200001
    Video Capture
    Streaming
    Extended Pix Format
Media Driver Info:
  Driver name      : uvcvideo
  Model            : Integrated Camera: Integrated C
  Serial           : 0001
  Bus info         : usb-0000:00:14.0-1
  Media version    : 5.15.53
  Hardware revision: 0x00000604 (1540)
  Driver version   : 5.15.53
Interface Info:
  ID               : 0x03000002
  Type             : V4L Video
Entity Info:
  ID               : 0x00000001 (1)
  Name             : Integrated Camera: Integrated C
  Function         : V4L2 I/O
  Flags            : default
  Pad 0x01000007   : 0: Sink
    Link 0x02000016: from remote pad 0x100000a of entity 'Microsoft Extended Controls Uni' (Video Pixel Formatter): Data, Enabled, Immutable
Priority: 2
Video input : 0 (Camera 1: ok)
Format Video Capture:
  Width/Height      : 1280/720
  Pixel Format      : 'MJPG' (Motion-JPEG)
  Field             : None
  Bytes per Line    : 0
  Size Image        : 1843200
  Colorspace        : sRGB
  Transfer Function : Rec. 709
  YCbCr/HSV Encoding: ITU-R 601
  Quantization      : Default (maps to Full Range)
  Flags             : 
Crop Capability Video Capture:
  Bounds      : Left 0, Top 0, Width 1280, Height 720
  Default     : Left 0, Top 0, Width 1280, Height 720
  Pixel Aspect: 1/1
Selection Video Capture: crop_default, Left 0, Top 0, Width 1280, Height 720, Flags: 
Selection Video Capture: crop_bounds, Left 0, Top 0, Width 1280, Height 720, Flags: 
Streaming Parameters Video Capture:
  Capabilities     : timeperframe
  Frames per second: 30.000 (30/1)
  Read buffers     : 0
                     brightness 0x00980900 (int)    : min=0 max=255 step=1 default=128 value=128
                       contrast 0x00980901 (int)    : min=0 max=100 step=1 default=32 value=32
                     saturation 0x00980902 (int)    : min=0 max=100 step=1 default=64 value=64
                            hue 0x00980903 (int)    : min=-180 max=180 step=1 default=0 value=0
 white_balance_temperature_auto 0x0098090c (bool)   : default=1 value=1
                          gamma 0x00980910 (int)    : min=90 max=150 step=1 default=120 value=120
           power_line_frequency 0x00980918 (menu)   : min=0 max=2 default=1 value=1 (50 Hz)
        0: Disabled
        1: 50 Hz
        2: 60 Hz
      white_balance_temperature 0x0098091a (int)    : min=2800 max=6500 step=10 default=4600 value=4600 flags=inactive
                      sharpness 0x0098091b (int)    : min=0 max=7 step=1 default=3 value=3
         backlight_compensation 0x0098091c (int)    : min=0 max=2 step=1 default=1 value=1
                  exposure_auto 0x009a0901 (menu)   : min=0 max=3 default=3 value=3 (Aperture Priority Mode)
        1: Manual Mode
        3: Aperture Priority Mode
              exposure_absolute 0x009a0902 (int)    : min=8 max=1250 step=1 default=156 value=156 flags=inactive
         exposure_auto_priority 0x009a0903 (bool)   : default=0 value=0
```

Comment: Yes, your hardware uses a lot of hardware not supported by Linux. It is [not certified](https://ubuntu.com/certified/laptops). Arch [documents](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Lenovo_Yoga_Slim_9_(Intel)) some tweaks here.. You'll have to translate that into the Ubuntu world